# ACAccount Facebook: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: ios6, facebook-access-token, social-framework, acaccount

I am using iOS 6 Social framework for accessing user's Facebook data. I am trying to get likes of the current user within my app using `ACAccount` and `SLRequest`. I have a valid Facebook account reference of type `ACAccount` named `facebook`, and I'm trying to get user's likes this way:

```
SLRequest *req = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:nil];
req.account = facebook;
[req performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
     //my handler code.
}
```

where `url` is `@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?fields=name";` In my handler, I'm getting this response:

```
{
error =     {
    code = 2500;
    message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
    type = OAuthException;
};
}
```

Shouldn't access tokens be handled by the framework? I've found a similar post [Querying Facebook user data through new iOS6 social framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270755/querying-facebook-user-data-through-new-ios6-social-framework) but it doesn't make sense to hard-code an access token parameter into the URL, as logically the access token/login checking should be handled automatically by the framework. In all examples that I've seen around no one plays with an access token manually:

http://damir.me/posts/facebook-authentication-in-ios-6

[iOS 6 Facebook posting procedure ends up with "remote_app_id does not match stored id" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644229/ios-6-facebook-posting-procedure-ends-up-with-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stor)
etc.

I am using the iOS6-only approach with the built in Social framework, and I'm not using the Facebook SDK. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Can.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: @JoãoNunes to be honest I don't remember. probably I've ended up using the Facebook SDK.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu hm.. did the same after 2hours lol

Answer (score 9):

You need to keep a strong reference to the ACAccountStore that the account comes from.  If the store gets deallocated, it looks like it causes this problem.

Comment: This is bit crazy but that was it. any problem if I have ACAccountStore as a property? After I set it as property, it worked perfectly. Thanks @Ethan

Answer (score 0):

Try running on an actual device instead of a simulator. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your bundle id is input into your Facebook app's configuration. You might have a different bundle id for your dev/debug build.