# Facebook authentication doesnot auto closes

Tags: facebook, ios6

I am trying to integrating Facebook-Connect SDK to a cocos2d-x game on iOS platform.

I am using the api,

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:TRUE
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
{

if(state == FBSessionStateOpen)
 NSLog(@"Success");

}
```

[image]

Dialog box doesn't close on pressing okay, however the completionHandler executes successfully with `FBSessionStateOpen`state.

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged this question iOS 6 so I'm assuming you are developing this game for iOS 6 devices which you'll be able to use iOS 6 integration with Facebook.

I explained how i did it once (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151853/1449151) but I put it here anyway. If you like to use iOS 6 Facebook integration you could follow these steps to make sure you did all of them right. (for instance I see your permission is nil, see how i did it below). Hope it helps:

OK here is how I do this integration with iOS 6 and get what I want from Facebook:

In AppDelegate I do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}
```

and in my ViewController where I want to retrieve information about myself or my friends I do this (NOTE: this is a test, so it is a lot of permissions!):

```
NSArray *permissions =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"user_location",
     @"user_birthday",
     @"user_likes", @"user_interests",@"friends_interests",@"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",@"friends_hometown",@"friends_photos",@"friends_status",
     @"friends_about_me", @"friends_birthday", @"friends_hometown", @"friends_interests", @"friends_likes", @"friends_location", nil];

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                      /* handle success + failure in block */
                                      if (status) {
                                          NSLog(@"Facebook Read Permission is successful!");
                                          [self presentPostOptions];

                                          //   [self presentPostOptions];


                                      }
                                  }];
```

Then in "presentPostOptions" I do this (in this example I try to retrieve something from my friend):

```
- (void)presentPostOptions
{

    [[FBRequest requestForMyFriends] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error)

     {

         if (!error) {

NSArray *data = [user objectForKey:@"data"];
             NSLog(@"%d", [data count]);
             for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", [friend first_name]);
                 NSLog(@"%@", [friend last_name]);
                 NSLog(@"%@", [friend id]);
                 //make sure you have FBProfilePictureView outlet in your view
                 //otherwise skip the profile picture!
                 self.fbProfilePic.profileID = @"you'r friend's profile.id";

             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"error");
             //  [self didFailWithError:error];
         }
     }];
```

I don't know what else you want to do because in your question you just tried to make a connection but this way you can do what ever you want while you are integrated in iOS 6.

One more thing, make sure about your App Settings over Facebook and the configs over there like enable your app for iOS and the ID for iPhone/iPad. Also the FacebookAppID in your plist.

Let me know if it works out for you,

EDIT: My Facebook SDK is 3.1.1 btw.