# Reading Twitter/Facebook information without Accounts via the iOS Social Framework

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, frameworks, social-framework

Is it possible to get Tweets/Facebook posts using the iOS Social Framework without using Facebook or Twitter accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to query data without active account.
You can create new SLRequest, even set its parameters with valid FB access token but you will still need to associate the request with valid, accessible account.

See the example of the possible request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270755/querying-facebook-user-data-through-new-ios6-social-framework)

For FB queries, You can use the FB SDK to perform the queries without active user login using access token generated for your facebook app, I can explain more about it if needed.

Comment: So it looks like it's possible for Facebook using their SDK. Is it possible with Twitter?